# Should I code in Sass or Scss?

Tags: syntax, sass, precompile

I much prefer the Sass syntax over the Scss syntax but I've noticed that the later is more popular, and I'm afraid of working in Sass and it no longer being supported in later versions.  I'm sorry if this is a repeated question, I couldn't find any answers in the search bar.

Comment: http://thesassway.com/news/sass-is-here-to-stay

Answer (score 10):

This is the explanation from the official [SASS website](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)

> **Sass** is an extension of CSS that adds power and elegance to the basic language. It allows you to use variables, nested rules, mixins, inline imports, and more, all with a fully CSS-compatible syntax. **Sass** helps keep large stylesheets well-organized, and get small stylesheets up and running quickly, particularly with the help of the Compass style library.
>
> There are two syntaxes available for **Sass**. The first, known as **SCSS** (Sassy CSS) and used throughout this reference, is an extension of the syntax of CSS3. This means that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is a valid **SCSS** file with the same meaning. In addition, **SCSS** understands most CSS hacks and vendor-specific syntax, such as IE’s old filter syntax. This syntax is enhanced with the Sass features described below. Files using this syntax have the **.scss** extension.
>
> The second and older syntax, known as the indented syntax (or sometimes just **“Sass”**), provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It uses indentation rather than brackets to indicate nesting of selectors, and newlines rather than semicolons to separate properties. Some people find this to be easier to read and quicker to write than **SCSS**. The indented syntax has all the same features, although some of them have slightly different syntax; this is described in the indented syntax reference. Files using this syntax have the

**SASS** was inspired by **HAML** and used the indentation convention. It was not very convenient for people who did not come from the HAML world. So the new syntax, **SCSS** was created which is a superset of the normal CSS syntax.

To answer your question `Should I code in Sass or Scss?`

You are better off going with **SCSS**, since there is not guarantee that a pre-compiler for **SASS** will be supported for long

Comment: Nathan Weizenbaum has stated that the indented syntax is here to stay - see my comment above.

Comment: @steveax That was more than 2 years ago. Thats a generation in tech world. I am not saying it will not be supported, I am just saying there is no guarantee - since there is no evidence (from recent past) about any activity in this regard.

Comment: Other languages (Python) use an indent-based syntax, so it's not only SASS that does it.

Comment: agreed. I correct myself - it should read "HAML/Python and any other indentation based language". The point I was making is that people familiar with `CSS` only (such as UI designers, who are not developers), will find it difficult to learn a new syntax.

Comment: @MrLister my reference to HAML specifically is because, the creator of both HAML and SASS is [Hampton Catlin](http://www.hamptoncatlin.com/). My statement about the original syntax of SASS - "SASS was inspired by HAML" is accurate.

Comment: Get your designers to write in SCSS (or hire better designers who actually want to work faster and charge you less) and have your devs write in SASS.  You don't need to take a major hit on dev productivity just to satisfy people uninterested in learning (something very very basic I might add).  The syntaxes are interchangeable (just not in the same file) and sass-convert does exist*.  *Sort of: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/188